# SQLCMD fails if -c; is specified in parameters on SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, sqlcmd

The following sqlcmd fails with no error and no output, just returns silently.

`SQLCMD -U dbuser -d dbname -w 255 -h-1 -P mypassword -S dbserver -Q "ALTER TABLE xyz ADD abcd NUMERIC(1)" -c;`

While it works fine without the `-c;` argument

`SQLCMD -U dbuser -d dbname -w 255 -h-1 -P mypassword -S dbserver -Q "ALTER TABLE xyz ADD abcd NUMERIC(1)"`

This parameter has been there since before 2005, with OSQL, then recently (less than a year ago) we replaced OSQL with SQLCMD.

And now we have discovered that one of our install scripts is not executing and it has come down to this `-c;` argument.

Also, I am testing on SQL Server 2019. I asked someone to execute the same scripts on a SQL Server 2008 and there the SQLCMD is working with the `-c;` parameter.

I have even tried specifying `:` and a few other characters instead of `;` to no avail.

How should this parameter be used? And if it is not recommended or not supported to use it any more, then please point to any documentation/bug report/release notes.

Comment: Could you please [check your SQLCMD version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15#check-version)? Also, could you try adding a space between the `-c` and the character (other than the semicolon)?

Comment: @Ronaldo - My sqlcmd version is `15. 0.2000.5 NT`. I had already tried ^, :, _ as terminators with and without space after -c. This parameter doesn't make sense to me anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [sqlcmd Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) doc says:

> **-c** *batch_terminator*
>  Specifies the batch terminator. By default, commands are terminated and sent to SQL Server by typing the word "GO"
> on a line by itself. When you reset the batch terminator, **do not use
> Transact-SQL reserved keywords or characters that have special meaning
> to the operating system**, even if they are preceded by a backslash. [emphasis mine]

And if you see the [Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) doc, you'll find that:

> ;        Transact-SQL statement terminator. Although the semicolon isn't
> required for most statements in this version of SQL Server, it will be
> required in a future version.

That info added to what Stewart Gordon pointed on [Why should I use a semicolon in SQL?](https://www.quora.com/Why-should-I-use-a-semicolon-in-SQL):

> The ANSI/ISO standards for SQL require statements to be separated by
> semicolons. As such, the majority of SQL implementations will require
> them. I think Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and earlier is one of the few
> that deviates from this standard.

From that I'd say the semicolon is now a reserved keyword, although it's not required yet on T-SQL.

---

### How to show the error message

> **Error Reporting Options**
> **-b** Specifies that sqlcmd exits and returns a DOS ERRORLEVEL value when an error occurs. The value that is returned to the DOS ERRORLEVEL
> variable is 1 when the SQL Server error message has a severity level
> greater than 10; otherwise, the value returned is 0. If the -V option
> has been set in addition to -b, sqlcmd will not report an error if the
> severity level is lower than the values set using **-V**. Command
> prompt batch files can test the value of ERRORLEVEL and handle the
> error appropriately. **sqlcmd** does not report errors for severity
> level 10 (informational messages).
>
> If the sqlcmd script contains an incorrect comment, syntax error, or
> is missing a scripting variable, ERRORLEVEL returned is 1.
>
> **-m** *error_level*
>  Controls which error messages are sent to **stdout**. Messages that have a severity level greater than or equal to this level are sent. When this value is set to -1, all messages
> including informational messages, are sent. Spaces are not allowed
> between the **-m** and **-1**. For example, **-m-1** is valid, and
> **-m -1** is not.
>
> This option also sets the sqlcmd scripting variable SQLCMDERRORLEVEL.
> This variable has a default of 0.

Answer (score 2):

When you look at the help from `sqlcmd /?`, the `-c` switch is listed as `[-c cmdend]`, which isn't helpful.

However, if you look at [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15), there is a much more helpful description:

> -c batch_terminator -
> Specifies the batch terminator. By default, commands are terminated and sent to SQL Server by typing the word "GO" on a line by itself. When you reset the batch terminator, do not use Transact-SQL reserved keywords or characters that have special meaning to the operating system, even if they are preceded by a backslash.

By passing `-c;` you're telling `sqlcmd` to send everything between `;`s to the server to execute it as separate batches. Since `;` is the (optional) statement terminator for SQL (and assuming that every statement *does* use the statement terminator), you're basically telling `sqlcmd` to send every statement as a separate batch, similar to having a GO after every statement.

Personally, I find code that uses non-standard batch terminators to be confusing. If you need every statement to be sent as a separate batch, insert `GO`s between them, and do not use the `-c` switch. That way, it will work with all the defaults in SSMS, sqlcmd, and other client tools.